# Bootstrap toggle button add-on with pgn image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a group of a label and text input, with a clickable button at the right of the text field. This button needs to be a toggle (gray when clicked, white when not clicked) and it should have a png image at it's logo.

I've made a simple code snippet to show you what I currently have:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group" style="float:left;">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%;"><img class="clIcon btn btn-default" src="http://dummyimage.com/15x15/26bf8f/fff" /></a></span> 
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

As you can see, my button actually has a white square in it, which is the actual toggle I am using. I want my toggle to **be** the button at the right side of the text area, and not only be *inside of it*.

Right now, only that small white square is clickable, not the whole button, which is a problem. I need the whole button to be clickable and to act like a toggle (on/off). I use this toggle to activate or deactivate the preview of an url in another page. The client has to be able to see if the preview will be active or not when the other page is loaded, with the color of the button (like any toggle).

Would you have any ideas? Thank you.

---

UPDATE

The look I want is the basic Bootstrap look, exactly like you can see in [the official documentation examples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons), where the `Go!` button would be a link, and the `Go!` text replaced by a `.png` image.

If possible, I would like to use the default bootstrap classes instead of building my own CSS on top of it or to replace it, as I want a uniformity with the other forms, where I use the official bootstrap classes to get the same look (for normal buttons, as an example).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you didn't reference scripts in right order.

jQuery should be referenced before bootstrap.js

Here is `<textarea>` and link with image inside it and "button" is resizible on resizing `<textarea>` https://jsfiddle.net/vmferrtx/4/

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    <span class="input-group-addon input-group-btn">
        <a href="#" class="link-button-right btn btn-default" type="button">
          <img class="clIcon" src="http://dummyimage.com/15x15/26bf8f/fff" />
        </a>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!-- /input-group -->
</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

with a bit of css:

```
    .link-button-right {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      width: 50px;
    }

    .input-group-addon {
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
    }

    .clIcon {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need the button to be an HTML link (that's why I had a `<a href` element), and to be a toggle (On/Off toggle when pressed with a change of color (like gray) when `On`).

Comment: Just replace <button> with <a> and leave css classes "btn btn-default".  https://jsfiddle.net/tnzv0otb/

Comment: I already do not have a `<button`. I added more code in my example to be pretty much exactly what I have. I'm sorry my 1st example was not clear enough. See my updated post for more informations (sorry about that).

Comment: Classes "btn btn-default" should be placed on <a> element, not on <img>

Comment: Moving the classes to `<a>` instead of `<img>` only added another layer of square inception. You can try it easily in my code snippet. It does not work.

Comment: In your code snippet you still have "<img class="clIcon btn btn-default" 
Remove "btn btn-default" from it. 
And check my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tnzv0otb/3/

Comment: Yes, I did, that is why I wrote *Moving the classes to* instead of *Addind the classes to*. It's not working. I did not save the changes to test this idea in my code snippet as it did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116709/discussion-between-bosko-kuzmanovic-and-david-g).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for is very hard to achieve with the bootstrap construct you are trying to use.  I wasn't able to do it without drastically changing the css to the `.input-group-addon` class or supplementing with javascript.  Below is the javascript version, but you might as well completely build the thing from scratch and forget about the group addon part (it uses `display:table`, which was causing problems with making the button fill that entire area).

In the below example, I use a `<label>` to make the whole area clickable.  I also include an `<input type="checkbox">` to create your toggleable state.  Then it's just a matter of using some variation of `label input[type=checkbox]:checked + whatever { ... }` to change background colors and apply other styles.  The javascript part just sets the checkbox's parent's background color because I could make the button image full width and height without nixing the `display: table` of `.input-group-addon` and company.  The result is what I think you wanted, but not at all in a clean and nice manner.  Again, I recommend just doing it from scratch and not using bootstrap's input group addon.

I also used `!important` instead of adding rules for `:focus`, `:active`, `:hover`, and God knows what else bootstrap adds to throw on those annoying box shadows and outlines.  I don't recommend doing that in production.

```js
$('label.input-group-addon input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
  $(this).closest('label').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background', $('.btn', this).css('background'));
  });
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
label.input-group-addon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.input-group-addon .btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none!important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
}

label.input-group-addon .btn:hover {
  background: white;
}

label.input-group-addon input:checked + .btn {
  background: #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group" style="float:left;">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    <label class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" class="sr-only">
      <img class="clIcon btn btn-default" src="http://dummyimage.com/15x15/26bf8f/fff" />
    </label> 
  </div>
</div>
```